# Installing python lib pymqi for MQ

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am trying to setup python pyqmi. I installed it for python 2.7. Post this when I do "import pymqi" and run it, I see error as-
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pymqi.py", line 104, in 
    import pymqe, CMQC, CMQCFC, CMQXC
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

I checked all the directory but did not find any python file called pymqe.py. Though I see a decrypted file of same as pymqe.pyd

Can someone please help me understanding what is going wrong here?

Comment: How did you install it?  Have you considered installing  Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)?  Doing so takes care of a tremendous amount of packaging issues – especially on Windows – and provides package/environment managers like `pip` and `conda`.

Comment: Hi- Thanks for checking this.....However I do not see pymqi package in https://www.continuum.io/downloads..am I checking anything wrong?

Comment: Anaconda comes with a number of popular scientific computing libraries on top of the standard-lib but does not come with everything.  Instead it provides package managers `pip` and `conda` to help you install and additional dependencies, like `pymqi`.  If you have Anaconda installed, go to cmd or powershell and run `pip install pymqi`.  Then you should be able to `import` it.

Comment: I get this on cmd screen..No matching distribution found for pymqi

I have python 2.7.2 and I installed anaconda 2.7.12 from https://www.continuum.io/downloads


  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044EBDA0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pymqi/  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymqi (from versions:)No matching distribution found for pymqi

Comment: what do you get when you do `python >>> import os >>> import sys >>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`?

Comment: it tells me the location where my python.exe is available...C:\Python27

Comment: That's not pointing to your Anaconda install.  You need to update the python path so that it points to your Anaconda install.  Did you use the Anaconda installer? This should have taken care of this for you.

Comment: I have also tried to run it from anaconda promt....I go to the location where anaconda is installed, in my case it is - C:\Users\XXXXXX\XXXX\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2> then run pip install pymqi......The problem is still the same

Comment: You need the python executable to be the one Anaconda set up.  See previous comment.  Perhaps rerun installer.